# What is the benefit of having linked storage account for HDInsight cluster?

Tags: azure-hdinsight, azure-data-factory

For an HDInsight cluster there has to be at least one azure storage account which is its default storage account -- it is required so that it is treated as its fs (filesystem). This I get. But what about optional linked azure storage accounts? From ADF (Azure Data Factory) perspective at least, do we need to have a storage account added as linked storage account to an HDInsight cluster? Anyway the Azure storage account is accessible purely by providing just two pieces of information --- the account name and the key. Both these things are specified in Linked Servers in ADF. This guarantees the access of the storage account. What is the real benefit of having some account added as linked storage account, from ADF point of view or otherwise? Basically, what I am asking is -- is there anything that we can't do purely using account name and key without adding the account as linked storage for the given HDInsight cluster?

Answer (score 1):

The main reason to have additional accounts is because they have limits. A storage account can have 500 TB of data in it and 20000 request per second.  Depending on the size of your cluster and work load you might hit the request limit. If you are worried about those limits  and you don't want to manage alot of storage accounts you should look into Azure Data Lake.

Comment: So, are you saying that if default storage account of an HDInsight cluster is exhausted in terms of space, the cluster data will automatically be diverted to the linked storage account, is that it?

Comment: No I don't believe that is how it would work... you have to manage that your self.

Comment: Then the question still remain open as to what is the benefit of having linked storage account. It's not going to switch over by itself. It's same as some storage account which is not linked storage account. What is the benefit? What is there that I can't do simply by having storage account name and its key that I have to define linked storage account for?

Answer (score 0):

I think I sort of figured out the answer. With linked storage accounts the cluster, when used as a compute, can directly access BLOBS on those storage accounts without requiring us to separately specify the storage keys in queries. That's the use case for which linked storage is a must have.